# SGE h_vmem vs java -Xmx -Xms

Tags: java, memory, cluster-computing, sungridengine

We have a couple of SGE clusters running various versions of RHEL at my work and we're testing a new one with a newer Redhat, all .  On the old cluster ("Centos release 5.4"), I'm able to submit a job like the following one and it runs fine:

`echo "java -Xms8G -Xmx8G -jar blah.jar ..." |qsub ... -l h_vmem=10G,virtual_free=10G ...`

On the new cluster "CentOS release 6.2 (Final)", a job with those parameters fails due to running out of memory, and I have to change the h_vmem to h_vmem=17G in order for it to succeed.  The new nodes have about 3x the RAM of the old node and in testing I'm only putting in a couple of jobs at a time.

On the old cluster, I'd set the `-Xms/Xms` to be `N`, I could use `N+1` or so for the `h_vmem`.  On the new cluster, I seem to be crashing unless I set `h_vmem` to be `2N+1`.

I wrote a tiny perl script that all it does is progressively use consume more memory and periodically print out the memory used until it crashes or it reaches a limit.  The h_vmem parameter makes it crash at the expected memory usage.

I've tried multiple versions of the JVM (1.6 and 1.7).  If I omit the `h_vmem`, it works, but then things are riskier to run.

I have googled where others have seen similar issues, but no resolutions found.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Just a friendly comment, you can use `backticks`  to format code inline.

Comment: Have you tried running your java program outside of SGE to see how much memory it is actually using when you pass it `-Xms8G -Xmx8G`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here appears to be an issue with the combination of the following factors:

1. The old cluster was RHEL5, and the new RHEL6
2. RHEL6 includes an update to glibc that changes the way MALLOC reports memory usage of multi-threaded programs.
3. the JVM includes a Multi-threaded garbage collector by default

To fix the problem I've used a combination of the following:

- Export the MALLOC_ARENA_MAX environment variable to a small number (1-10) e.g. in the job script. I.e. include something like:  `export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=1`
- Moderately increased the SGE memory requests by 10% or so
- Explicitly set the number of java GC threads to a low number by using `java -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 ...`
- Increased the SGE thread requests.  E.g.  `qsub -pe pthreads 2`

Note that it's unclear that setting the MALLOC_ARENA_MAX all the way down to 1 is the right number, but low numbers seem to work well from my testing.

Here are the links that lead me to these conclusions:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/linux_glibc_2_10_rhel_6_malloc_may_show_excessive_virtual_memory_usage?lang=en

[What would cause a java process to greatly exceed the Xmx or Xss limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575342/what-would-cause-a-java-process-to-greatly-exceed-the-xmx-or-xss-limit)

http://siddhesh.in/journal/2012/10/24/malloc-per-thread-arenas-in-glibc/