# Limit total memory consumption of Java process (in Cloud Foundry)

Tags: java, memory, jvm, out-of-memory, cloud-foundry

Related to these two questions:

- [How to set the maximum memory usage for JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493913/how-to-set-the-maximum-memory-usage-for-jvm)
- [What would cause a java process to greatly exceed the Xmx or Xss limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575342/what-would-cause-a-java-process-to-greatly-exceed-the-xmx-or-xss-limit/12232725)

I run a Java application on Cloud Foundry and need to make sure that the allocated memory is not exceeded. Otherwise, and this is the current issue, the process is killed by Cloud Foundry monitoring mechanisms (Linux CGROUP).

The Java Buildpack automatically sets sane values for `-Xmx` and `-Xss`. By tuning the arguments and configuring the (maximum) number of expected threads, I'm pretty sure that the memory consumed by the Java process should be less than the upper limit which I assigned to my Cloud Foundry application.

However, I still experience Cloud Foundry "out of memory" errors (**NOT** the Java OOM error!):
`index: 3, reason: CRASHED, exit_description: out of memory, exit_status: 255`

I experimented with the `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX` setting. Setting the value to 1 or 2 leads to slow startups. With `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4` I still saw an error as described above, so this is no solution for my problem.

Currently I test with very tight memory settings so that the problem is easier to reproduce. However, even with this, I have to wait about 20-25 minutes for the error to occur.

Which arguments and/or environment variables do I have to specify to ensure that my Java process **never** exceeds a certain memory limit? Crashing with a Java OOM Error is acceptable if the application actually needs more memory.

Further information regarding `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX`:

- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/pull/160
- https://www.infobright.com/index.php/malloc_arena_max/#.VmgdprgrJaQ
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/linux_glibc_2_10_rhel_6_malloc_may_show_excessive_virtual_memory_usage?lang=en

EDIT: A possible explaination is this: http://www.evanjones.ca/java-bytebuffer-leak.html. As I currently see the OOM issue when doing lots of outgoing HTTP/REST requests, these buffers might be to blame.

Comment: How tight is tight?  We've seen that the JVM `native` memory consumption balloons on startup (it's pretty opaque as to what's going on) but eventually returns all that native memory to the OS as startup proceeds.  You might be running into that.

Comment: Tight as in less than 10 MByte of free space, I think I managed to get it to less than 1 MByte. And how long does that ballooning take? Seconds? Minutes?

Comment: Seconds, but typically long enough that it will trigger the container's defenses.  If you're seeing the container get involved later than that, it's likely you're seeing `native` memory growth.

Comment: OK. Thank you. My service crashes after about 20 minutes.

Comment: "Run services with -Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=262144 to avoid this problem." explained in Evan Jones's blog post is a useful tip. That feature was backported to 8u102, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8147468

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to definitively enforce a memory limit on the JVM.  Most of the memory regions are configurable (`-Xmx`, `-Xss`, `-XX:MaxPermSize`, `-XX: MaxMetaspaceSize`, etc.) but the one you can't control is Native memory.  Native memory contains a whole host of things from memory mapped files to native libraries to JNI code.  The best you can do is profile your application, find out where the memory growth is occurring, and either solve the growth or give yourself enough breathing room to survive.

Certainly unsatisfying, but in the end not much different from other languages and runtimes that have **no** control over their memory footprint.