# Thread issues on Cloud

Tags: multithreading, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud, cloud-foundry

**Will thread create any issues in the Cloud while scaling the application either horizontally or Vertically?**

The objective is to migrate the monolith applications to Cloud Suitable application which is basically need to support scaling without any cloud issues.  Primarily , We are focusing on Pivotal Cloud Foundry but i would like to other Cloud enviornment as well. Is there any common checkList whether these list of thread patterns will support in Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Any app instance, in PCF, is constrained to the resource it has been allocated at runtime. If your app instance runs out of resources (memory, disk), it simply crashes. PCF will then spin up a new instance.

PCF manages the atomic instance of an app. Simple answer PCF auto scaling (horizontal or vertical) doesn't care how many threads your app instance creates or what else it does.

The threads for an app instance are completely up to that app instance.

Ben Hale provided a great answer on this thread - [Limit total memory consumption of Java process (in Cloud Foundry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180422/limit-total-memory-consumption-of-java-process-in-cloud-foundry)

Comment: Thank you @K.AJ . But i would like to know that will it make the issues of application state management. I mean that Cloud expects that all transactions should be stateless. I'm not sure that Whether thread makes any problem in Application state management like assumed that  instance -1 value might be corrupted by instance-2 value in Cloud?

Comment: Your application should not cache any data. If it needs caching, use a service like Redis or Gemfire. So, the app instance is totally stateless. 

Not clear about your use case. Please read up on [12 Factor Principles for Cloud Native Apps](12factor.net).